# How to inherit from silverlight Button?

Tags: silverlight

I need to have button have 4 images that are changed by the application action.

I want to define new class ButtonEx that inherit from the Button class.

So, i did it by adding 'silverlight template control' and it to be inherit from control to Button.

Now, i cant see the images whan i put this ButtonEx on the page.

What i did wrong ?

How to fix it ?

( same code work fine in WPF )

Comment: What do you mean by application action?

Comment: Some action that the app. do - like scrol bar button press and ext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post any of your code? Did you create a visual style for it in themes\generic.xaml? Did you set the default style key?

I recently followed this tutuorial for a TextBox, you could so something similar for your button... http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Create-a-Custom-Control-Inheriting-from-TextBox.aspx

Comment: Yes, I created themes\generic.xaml - and i define the default style key to same as the class name ( do i need to define the default to be 'Button' ?  )

Comment: You need to set the default style key to the type of your class so typeof(ButtonEx)/ Then the style in your generic.xaml needs to have the target type set to ButtonEx

Answer (score 1):

Store your images as resources then create a user control that has
- a button and the content of the button is an image
- a property to select the image from the resources

use the usercontrol as your button.

Answer (score 1):

please post a code sample...

to inherit form button you simply need this.

public class ButtonEx:Button

{

}

this will have all functionality that button has.
if you want new template just add it in Themes/generic.xaml

Answer (score 1):

From your question its not clear that you really need to be subclassing Button.   Maybe you can get by with just copying and modifying the template of button (Blend helps for this),  or just have the image as content bound to some property for the application to change (using a ValueConverter perhaps).